# How to write to stdout with Ruby on Bluemix?

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix Ruby buildpack out of the box.
I add some puts lines in my main *.rb file but nothing appears when tailing logs:

```
cf logs myapp
```

Searching the docs, I found [this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/21548/debugging-a-ruby-app-in-bluemix-with-puts-or-print-statements-written-to-the-log-is-it-possible.html) post at developerWorks where it is recommended to set runtime into development mode.

I have tried with:

```
cf set-env myapp RAILS_ENV development
```

and also adding to the code:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'
```

but nothing appears in the logs.

Also tried Sinatra options (after changing the code) with same results:

```
set :environment, :development
set :logging, true
```

An interesting thing, is that if I stop the app, then all my puts appears after the stacktrace of the  FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM error. It seems like a buffer flush contention or anything like that?

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following line to your `config.ru` file.  This will disable buffering to stdout and allows your `puts` commands to stdout to appear correctly in the log output.

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

See the answer at [What STDOUT.sync = true means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998728/what-stdout-sync-true-means) for more details about how puts buffers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of this... worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Not Sure but have you tried the following links

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/21548/debugging-a-ruby-app-in-bluemix-with-puts-or-print-statements-written-to-the-log-is-it-possible.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-commandline/

Comment: the first one is the url I already commented as tried in my question. The second one, I don't see how it helps...

Comment: @Amol - this should be added as comments not answers.