# Ruby's output in the Windows console VS mingw64 VS cygwin64

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, mingw, windows-console

I'm having a really weird problem here. Here's simple code that uses *puts*:

```
puts "Dale"
sleep 1
puts "Cooper"
```

I have 3 different terminals/consoles:

- *Windows console* (system default)
- *mingw64* (UNIX-like terminal that was installed alongside with Git)
- *cygwin64* (UNIX-like terminal)

Here is weird thing: the code runs as expected only in the standard Windows console. UNIX-like terminals are waiting for 1 second and only then showing output (both lines at the same moment). Basically, UNIX-like terminals are waiting for the program to exit, and then they are showing the final result of output.

If I replace *puts* with *print*, it wont affect the execution process. UNIX-like terminals will still delay output until the program quits.

But the next two examples work right in all 3 terminals/consoles:

```
system("echo Dale")
sleep 1
system("echo Cooper")
```

This one adds quotes, but aside from this, the code works as expected.

```
p "Dale"
sleep 1
p "Cooper"
```

Having said this, I assume this has something to do with Ruby. I have tried different versions of Ruby.

Can someone explain why this is happening and what are possible ways to bypass this issue?

Comment: Typically with alternate terminals, they actually use a named pipe for standard I/O in order to communicate with the terminal application. Many applications see that standard I/O is a pipe and switch to full buffering mode instead of line buffering. The Windows console, on the other hand, uses files for the ConDrv device, which is a character device, and thus applications use line buffering or no buffering when standard I/O is a console.

Comment: The Ruby interpreter may support command-line options or environment variables to control buffering when standard I/O is a pipe or disk file.

Comment: @eryksun wise edit, thank you. What would you suggest to do with buffering?

Comment: Usually the options are no buffering, line buffering (i.e. flush when LF or CRLF is written), or full buffering (e.g. a 4 KB buffer that may not flush until the process exits, if not much is written).

Comment: @eryksun thank you for your help! Basically you did answer my question! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's me answering my own question.

#### Little background

If you do `puts STDOUT.sync` before the code then you will see that no matter if you are using Windows console or UNIX-like terminal, it will say that *STDOUT.sync* is set to *false*. That's weird thing because Windows console is flushing output immediately and UNIX-like terminals don't. I'm not sure why that's happening.

#### Solution

You can do `STDOUT.flush` (or `$stdout.flush`) to flush buffer or you can set *STDOUT.sync* (or *$stdout.sync*) to *true*. Both variants are completely friendly with Windows console. So the code will be as following:

```
puts "Dale"
STDOUT.flush
sleep 1
puts "Cooper"
```

or more recommended:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
puts "Dale"
sleep 1
puts "Cooper"
```

#### Determining whenever it's Windows console or UNIX-like terminal

Here is a little trick suggested by [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) to know if code is being run in Windows console or UNIX-like terminal. *STDOUT.isatty* works kind of inverted when run under Windows, but nevertheless it does the trick.

```
if STDOUT.isatty
    # Windows console
else
    # UNIX-like terminal
end
```

Keep in mind that this assumes that you already know that the code is being run under Windows. A good way to check OS is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171011/8410844).

#### References

Major source for the answer can be found [here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/07/04/stdout-sync-true-to-flush-output-immediately.html). Idea for the answer belongs to [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun).

[*STDOUT.sync*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-sync),
[*STDOUT.sync =*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998728/8410844) about this method),
[*STDOUT.flush*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-flush), [*STDOUT.isatty*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-isatty).

Comment: There are lots of versions of bash available for Windows, including Windows 10's WSL bash. The presence of bash in `PATH` doesn't mean you're using a UNIX-like terminal. I think the salient difference is whether stdout is seen as a disk/pipe file or a character file. Sometimes the latter is called a tty, even on Windows even though Windows doesn't have tty/pty devices. Look for a method like `isatty`.

Comment: @eryksun you are right. Though it's kinda funny that `STDOUT.isatty` is returning *true* on Windows console and *false* on UNIX-like terminals. Anyway this is a way steadier method to rely on. Thank you, once again.

Comment: It's expected that isatty is false for UNIX-like terminals on Windows. They're forced to use named pipes for the standard handles, since Windows doesn't have UNIX pty/tty devices.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for clearing that. Updated the answer.